# Boolean Algebra : Prove that

Tags: boolean-logic, booleanquery

I was having trouble with the following problem in boolean algebra i.e.

> A+A'B = A+B

I need to prove the above section. I mean its already reduced i can't reduce it further.

Comment: Why not just use a truth table to prove it? I think it is an identity.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A + A'B = (A + A') (A + B) = 1 (A + B) = A + B

Comment: How did you manage to get the first expression? i.e. A+A'B = (A + A')(A+B) is there any method for that?

Comment: @timrau we are getting extra term AB after you expand (A + A')(A+B)

Comment: @Raptor How did you _expand_ (A+A')(A+B)?

Answer (score 13):

A+A'B = A.1 + A'B = A.(1+B)+A'B = A.1+A.B+A'B = A + B.(A+A') = A + B.1 = A + B

Comment: which rule did you apply for every step?

Comment: How did you right this: `A.1 + A'B = A.(1+B)+A'B`?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

First taking NOT on both sides and then apply De-Morgan's Law on both sides:

```
L.H.S=

(A+A'B)'
=(A'.(A'B)')
=(A'.(A+B')) //again applied de-morgan's law in previous step
=(A'.A + A'B')
=A'B'

also apply De-morgans on RHS
(A+B)'
=A'B'
```

Thus LHS = RHS

Comment: I havnt studied de-morgan yet its the next topic :D thanks though i'll comeback after im done with it

Comment: Its easy to understand. Just google it if u are too curious about it :)